# Does every modular form of higher levels generated by Eisenstein series?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

For level 1 modular form, it is known that every modular form can be represented as a polynomial in weight 4 and 6 Eisenstein series. I wonder if this is true for higher levels. Interestingly, I found some papers that consider the problem of building modular forms as a linear combination of products of *at most two* of Eisenstein series. Here are related papers:

- Raum & Xia, [All modular forms of weight 2 can be expressed by Eisenstein series](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40993-020-00207-z)
- Dickson & Neururer, [PRODUCTS OF EISENSTEIN SERIES AND FOURIER EXPANSIONS OF MODULAR FORMS AT CUSPS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00774.pdf)

If we allow arbitrary number of products (of Eisenstein series), is it true that they generate all modular forms?

Comment: Khuri-Makdisi has proved that for every $N \geq 3$, the algebra generated by Eisenstein series of weight 1 on $\Gamma(N)$ contains all modular forms of weight $\geq 2$ on $\Gamma(N)$, see his article 'Moduli interpretation of Eisenstein series'. (Also, 'Neurural' should be 'Neururer'.)

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thanks! I edited the name.